# Rewriting ret in x86

Tags: x86

I am trying to return in an x86 program without using the ret instruction.

So far I have

```
add %rsp, 4
jmp  dword ptr [%rsp -4]
```

But I get error: junk after dword ptr[%rsp -4]

Comment: Is this supposed to be GAS or MASM syntax? or something else?

Comment: If you’re in long mode, and using `%rsp`, wouldn’t the return address be 8 bytes long?

Comment: Your error and syntax suggests you are using GNU Assembler `as`  intended to be used with `.intel_prefix` directive. If you want to use at&t syntax (default) that would be: `add $8, %rsp` `jmp *-8(%rsp)`. With `.intel_syntax` it would be `add %rsp, 8` `jmp [%rsp-8]`, and with `intel_syntax noprefix` it would be `add rsp, 8` `jmp [rsp-8]`

Comment: You can get away with this on 64-bit Linux because of the red zone, but doing this is dangerous on 32-bit code since an asynchronous event could occur between the add and the jmp and could clobber the return address before you jump to it.

Comment: I'm curious why you are trying to do this?

Comment: `ret` doesn't clobber flags.  Use `lea` to add 8 to RSP if you want to exactly duplicate the architectural effects of `ret` (https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/RET).  (Not the microarchitectural / performance effects, of course!  This is really bad for performance because it mismatches call/ret, breaking return-address prediction for later `ret`s).  But note that you either need a scratch register or an ABI with a red zone (like on Linux/OS X) to emulate `pop RIP` (aka `ret`) with multiple instructions.  (Like Michael Petch pointed out).